# How can I detect if HTTPOnly is set in php without looking to code?

Tags: php, cookies, httponly

I have xampp server installed in my machine. (php v5.3)
I put a website on it. It's written in php. It work with cookie (PHPSESSIONID). The source code is encrypted.
Is there a way to know if HTTPOnly field is set in source code of this website ?
The problem is that the server override the value of HTTPOnly in php.ini.

Comment: The source is encrypted?

Comment: I mean it's encoded through Zend Guard.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the page in firefox and view the cookies (I think it's part of the webdeveloper addon), it will tell you if it is a secure cookie and if it is httponly.